# Should I use prometheus or influxdb

Tags: influx-db

I know this has been asked a lot of times and I've checked almost all of the links out there but just want to have a third-party opinion on our use case.

So I'm working for an IOT company and we already have prometheus installed on our servers. Primarily we use prometheus to monitor the server and app's health and some sensor-related data. Now we have a new feature where we need to save the data when an IOT device changes location.

I did a bit of reading on prometheus and read about a line on their comparison page: https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/comparison/#prometheus-vs-influxdb

> Where InfluxDB is better:
>
> - If you're doing event logging.
> - Commercial option offers clustering for InfluxDB, which is also better for long term data storage.
> - Eventually consistent view of data between replicas.

So did a bit of reading about influxdb and it seems the right tool for our use case. Was wondering if we can just continue using prometheus as our time-series database rather than adding another tool which we need to maintain in the future. Or does it make sense to use a proper time-series database not just for monitoring (as I believe what the original intention of creating prometheus was).

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus is a time-series database. The question is, do you need more data types and a stronger query language? What type of data is saved for location? Geo coordinates?

It also depends on your availability requirements. Both InfluxDB and Prometheus are single node. InfluxDB supports clustering only if you purchase the enterprise version.

For Prometheus, you need multiple instances to ensure high availability and they will be scraping the same data in duplicate. If your data requirements are high, you may have to look into long term remote storage. https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#remote-storage-integrations.

We have developed a new serverless time-series database as a service called Hyprcubd. Full disclosure, I’m the founder.  It was architected with IoT in mind. It supports multiple data types, long term storage, and high availability. https://www.hyprcubd.com